# Can I hide sensitive property values from a c# 9 record's autogenerated methods?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I'm building a user management system, with a domain host to which I am sending commands. The commands are `record`s both because of the `init`-only properties and because of the generated helper methods. However, I quickly ran into a problem with this approach for e.g. the `LoginUserCommand`.

`command.ToString()` returns something like this (formatting added):

```
LoginUserCommand { 
    Identity = 10000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444,
    CorrelationId = 20000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444,
    Timestamp = 2013-07-26T16:45:20Z,
    IssuingUserId = 30000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444,
    EntityId = a80c081c-cf91-4304-9baa-20fb20c8d9f7,
    IPAddress = 127.0.0.1,
    Password = ThisIsAPr0blem
}
```

Obviously I can work around this by e.g. overriding `ToString()` on the classes where it matters. Naïvely, I might do something like

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return base.ToString()
        .Replace(Password, "********");
}
```

But I'm wondering whether I've overlooked some built-in way to have the generated `ToString()` method mask the value of the `Password` property.

Comment: Could [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) be an option?

Comment: @BillTür - [Microsoft recommends against using it for _anything_](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Comment: [Specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#printing-members-printmembers-and-tostring-methods) shows the built-in way, you may override `PrintMembers` method

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I can't seem to override the `PrintMembers` method. https://dotnetfiddle.net/reO2XV

Comment: @diemaus Replace `override` with `virtual`. You can only use `override` when the record is inheriting another record. But if you want to prevent the compiler from generating PrintMembes, then you provide the implementation you want as `virtual`.

Comment: I've also created a source generator for that. Consider giving it a look. <https://github.com/Youssef1313/PrintMembersGenerator>. You can fork it and continue developing it on your own, send PRs, or file issues for features/bugs you want me to work on.

Comment: @Youssef13 - the accepted answer mentions and has a link to your project. Thank you for your work on that! Unfortunately at this point this is not a big enough pain point that I can prioritize contributing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can remap your record with the `with` syntax and use `PrintMembers` instead, which I think is cleaner:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    
    (this with { Password = null }).PrintMembers(builder);

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

There have also been [proposals](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3925) for introducing an attribute such as `[PrintMembersIgnore]` for records, but nothing like it has been implemented. It can however be solved with code generation, which was the method suggested by the dotnet team (see comment in the thread), a [project for this](https://github.com/Youssef1313/PrintMembersGenerator/) has been started.

Comment: Definitely much cleaner. The most common place that `ToString()` will be called is when the application is logging commands. It's logging them at debug, but still, there's no reason to leave this info available if it can be avoided.

Comment: I tried playing around with a base record and overriding `ToString` there instead, but the override is not inherited by superrecords (is this the correct term?).

Comment: I added some additional info which might be of interest

Comment: In ToString() why are you using StringBuilder and not directly using following ?
    (this with { Password = null }).ToString();

Comment: @techExplorer since that would cause an endless recursive call (and then a StackOverflow).

Comment: @mausworks - with regards to a base class override of `ToString()` being used by derived record types:

As of C# 10 you can add `sealed` to the base class `ToString()` and the compiler will no longer try to add its own implementation when compiling derived record types.

cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#built-in-formatting-for-display

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate sensitive properties in derived class and override `PrintMembers`.

```cs
var s = new Entity("ss11", 99, "supersecret");
Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine(s.secret);
// Output:
// EntityWithSecret { s1 = ss11, i2 = 99 }
// supersecret

public record EntityNoSecret(string s1, int i2);
public record Entity(string s1, int i2, string secret) : EntityNoSecret(s1, i2)
{
    protected override bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder)
        => base.PrintMembers(builder);
};
```